# CakePHP: Prefix in URL for each team

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm developing an CakePHP 3 web site. I would like to show content based on the team. And in each controller i would like to access the current team.

E.g.:

> www.url.com/team1 --> Team = team1, Controller = Home, Action = Index
>
> www.url.com/team2 --> Team = team2, Controller = Home, Action = Index
>
> www.url.com/team3 --> Team = team3, Controller = Home, Action = Index
>
> ...

I want to use the same controller for all teams, except that the shown content is based on the team. What is the best to accomplish this? Routing seems not to work for me, I played around a little.

Comment: Routing system works fine and it's pretty much the only option here. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: Why don't you turn it around? www.url.com/home/index/team1 And then  team1 is passed as a parameter. You could also choose to route the first param as the team, but then if you got a url like /contact cakephp will not know if it is a team, or a contact page.

Answer (score 1):

```php
// HomeController.php
public function index($team = null) {
    echo 'Hello Team ' . $team;
}

// routes.php
Router::connect(
    '/team:id', 
    ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'Index'],
    ['id' => '[0-9]+']
);
```

[Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)

Answer (score 0):

just use your **routes.php** :)

In routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/team/*', array('controller'=>'Home', 'action'=>'index'));
In products_controller.php:
```

In Controller.php

```
function index($id = null) {
    echo "Team" . $id;
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html